# R Shiny - Generating PDF report

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, r-markdown

I need to generate and download a PDF report from a shiny app. I've found this (I've placed the app.R and report.Rmd files in the same folder):

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html

````
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
),
server = function(input, output) {
output$report <- downloadHandler(
  # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
  filename = "report.html",
  content = function(file) {
    # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
    # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
    # can happen when deployed).
    tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
    file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

    # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
    params <- list(n = input$slider)

    # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
    # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
    # from the code in this app).
    rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
      params = params,
      envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
    )
  }
)
}
)

report.Rmd:

---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
n: NA
---

```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
```

A plot of `params$n` random points.
````

The problem is, when I run it and press download, I get the following error:

```
Warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0SaXzj\report.Rmd": Das      System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
Warning: Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute: file 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0SaXzj\report.Rmd' does not exist
Stack trace (innermost first):
57: tools::file_path_as_absolute
56: dirname
55: setwd
54: rmarkdown::render
53: download$func [#255]
 4: <Anonymous>
 3: do.call
 2: print.shiny.appobj
 1: <Promise>
Error : file 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0SaXzj\report.Rmd' does not exist
```

After a bit of checking I've seen that the copy step does not work, with the error:

```
file.copy("report.Rmd", "/test/report.Rmd")
>FALSE
```

On one hand I think the problem is I am not in the correct folder, and on the other that I can't access the tempDir.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the `tempReport` subdirectory exist? Try creating it beforehand with `dir.create`.

Comment: I think that the idea of tempdir() is actually to allow creation of a PDF file in a separate temp folder, running and than deletion. I tried creating the subdir first, didn't help.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the error on my machine.  but I have full write access on my machine.  Maybe the write access is still your problem?  Perhaps `tempdir()` is failing.

Comment: `tempdir` only gives you a place to put a temporary directory, it does not create it. Try `dir.exists` before the copy to be sure.

Comment: Being insanely late, but thank you all! Sebastian-c if you want you can post your comment as an answer, and I will accept it.